# Are Landsat 8 data from ESPA corrected and calibrated?

Tags: remote-sensing, landsat-8, band, atmospheric-correction, toa-calibration

I am trying to figure out Landsat 8 data corrections and calibrations. Actually, I don't really know how this can be done and which data needs what kind of correction and calibration for further processing. Basically new for these processing. So, I prefer to download already corrected and calibrated Landsat scenes.

I have downloaded Landsat 8 OLI/TIRS C1 Level-1 data from https://glovis.usgs.gov/. It seems that there is no correction and calibration. I got following data in the package.

```
LC08_L1TP_129026_20140712_20170421 = *

        *_01_T1_b1 to b11
        *_01_T1_bqa
        *_01_T1_MTL
        *_01_T1_ANG
```

Also I downloaded same scene from https://espa.cr.usgs.gov/. It supposed to be corrected and calibrated. I guess it is. Because the value range of band data are different. Following are the additional data plus the above package, cause I ticked TOA calibrated, and SR, ST and angle corrected.

```
*_01_T1_sr_band1 to band7
*_01_T1_toa_band1 to band9
*_01_T1_pixel_qa
*_01_T1_radsat_qa
*_01_T1_sr_aerosol
*_01_T1_sensor_azimuth_band4
*_01_T1_sensor_zenith_band4
*_01_T1_solar_azimuth_band4
*_01_T1_solar_zenith_band4
```

Are the data downloaded from https://espa.cr.usgs.gov/ corrected and calibrated to be used for further analysis directly?

I am wondering, if the band data already corrected and calibrated, what are the additional data for (i.e. sr_band1-band7, _01_T1_toa_band1-band9, _01_T1_sensor_azimuth_band4 and _01_T1_sensor_zenith_band4)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, these are the Level 2 data products, which are calibrated to surface reflectance. These are able to be used for further analysis directly.

- ***_01_T1_sr_band1 to band7** refers to the surface reflectance (bottom of atmosphere) products
- ***_01_T1_toa_band1 to band9** refers to the top of atmosphere products

The remaining bands are quality assessment bands--as described by the USGS:

> Landsat Surface Reflectance products include Quality Assessment (QA)
>   bands to identify the pixels that exhibit adverse instrument,
>   atmospheric, or surficial conditions.  Used effectively, QA
>   information improves the integrity of science investigations by
>   indicating which pixels might be affected by instrument artifacts or
>   subject to cloud contamination.

And further described in great detail here:

https://landsat.usgs.gov/landsat-surface-reflectance-quality-assessment

Comment: So, *_01_T1_sr_band1 to band7 are corrected to surface reflectance and *_01_T1_toa_band1 to band9 are bands corrected to top of atmosphere of the uncorrected bands data (Level 1), respectively, right? What about If I wanted corrected band data to both of them and others (sensor_zenith, solar_azimuth) in single layer?

Comment: Yes, for the first question. I'm unclear what you are looking for in the second question--could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

level 1 product does not have atmospheric correction 
https://landsat.usgs.gov/does-landsat-level-1-data-processing-include-atmospheric-correction you need to download level 2 product for atmospheric correction. I use earth explorer  to download landsat data https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/ choose your level from options in datasets. here is more information with Level 1 data https://landsat.usgs.gov/landsat-processing-details about geometric corrections and radiometric calibration. I hope it helps. Good luck!